# How return from callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm struggling with some nodejs code (with this library https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-exif).

```
new ExifImage({image: image}, function (error, exifData) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    }

    else {
        console.log(exifData); // Do something with your data!
    }
});
```

My question is how to retrieve `exifData` outside? I don't want to embed my code inside because is pretty big.
I need this to be synchronous.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a larger piece of code? Where do you use this?

Comment: I need to execute this code several times in my code, so I don't want to copy 3 times this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function handleExifData(exifData){
   // Do something with your data!
}

new ExifImage({image: image}, function (error, exifData) {
                        if (error)
                            console.log('Error: ' + error.message);

                        else 
                            handleExifData(exifData);
                    });
```

Comment: Does not really solves my problem, but I can do something with this.

Comment: I don't I completely understood the quest but you could also try using promisify from nodejs's util library.

Comment: Later on the code, I need to build a json and one of the field is the value of the exifData.

Comment: Basically what I would like is to have var myData = getMyExifData(); Then I could do whatever I want with myData.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a combination of promisify and async await to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: can you share with me something like that ? I'm a newbie in javascript (I am a Java developper and all this is unknown for me). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Varaibles outside of the function of your callback are in scope too. You could just create a Variable above your Line with the callback and write the content to it in the callback.

You have to make sure that ypur callback is executed, before you use that variable too.

Hope this helps :)